# EJB abstract remote bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I am developing Java6 web-app (.war) deployed onto glassfish-3 server. Part of my logic, concerned with DB connections etc. is part of another project - .ear deployed along with my app. It all worked well until instead of a simple managed beans I had to create another layer of abstraction to injected logic. Maybe the code will explain it best.

My web-app:

```
public class OtherClass  {

    @EJB(name = "IClass", mappedName = "A")
    private IClass iClass;
    
    }
}
```

.ear deployed app:

```
public abstract class AbClass {...}

@Stateless(name = "IClass", mappedName = "A")
public class A extends AbClass implements IClass {...}

@Stateless(name = "IClass", mappedName = "B")
public class B extends AbClass implements IClass {...}
```

Common imports (another project as a maven dependency):

```
@Remote
public interface IClass extends Serializable {...}
```

However that does not work and while trying to resolve `@EJB` throws:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: A#.com.example.IClass not found
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=IClass,Remote 3.x interface =com.example.IClass,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=A,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class com.example.ItherClass: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/IClass' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

I am aware I could work around that problem for example by creating a Factory, but I was under the impression that that approach should work.